# Are there ways of easily sorting a list of objects like this in Javasript?

Tags: javascript

I have a Node class

```
class Node:

def __init__(self, move = None, parent = None, state = None):
    self.move = move 
    self.parentNode = parent # "None" for the root node
    self.childNodes = []
    self.wins = 0
    self.visits = 0
    self.untriedMoves = state.GetMoves() # future child nodes
    self.playerJustMoved = state.playerJustMoved # the only part of the state that the Node needs later

def UCTSelectChild(self):
    """ Use the UCB1 formula to select a child node. Often a constant UCTK is applied so we have
        lambda c: c.wins/c.visits + UCTK * sqrt(2*log(self.visits)/c.visits to vary the amount of
        exploration versus exploitation.
    """
    s = sorted(self.childNodes, key = lambda c: c.wins/c.visits + sqrt(2*log(self.visits)/c.visits))
    return s
```

I have a list of these Node objects.

In Python I can easily sort like so..

```
        s = sorted(self.childNodes, key = lambda c: c.wins/c.visits + sqrt(2*log(self.visits)/c.visits))
```

Best way to do this in Javascript? This is my first day using Javascript..

Comment: Can you post the Node class and example of the data?

Comment: You should also attach what is the input and what do you want as output.

Comment: @SajeebAhamed Input is a list of objects as described above and I have attached the desired output, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method of the `Array`.

```
array = [...];
array = array.sort();
```

This will sort the array based on the default comparison logic. If you want to provide your own comparison logic, you can just pass a **compare function** as an argument. Unlike Python's `key` where you consume just one parameter, the compare function provides `firstElement` and `secondElement` as the parameters. So, you might do something like this:

```
array = array.sort((firstEl, secondEl) => {
    let first = firstEl.wins / firstEl.visits + sqrt(2 * Math.log(firstEl.visits)/firstEl.visits);
    let second = secondEl.wins / secondEl.visits + sqrt(2 * Math.log(secondEl.visits)/secondEl.visits);

    return first - second;
});
```

Surely, this seems a bit more verbose but that's how it is.